# How to add an delay between methods that are performing a large task

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

I have a button click event that will call methods that will start services on a remote server. It fails whenever I have to start a large amount of server services such as 20. How can I be certain that all services will starts correctly and not fail? I've read that you can use Thread or Async Delay to add some time in between methods. I'm not sure which is the best to use. Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
protected void StartServices_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ServerOne_Start();
    // What should I add between these two methods that will provide some time
    // for ServerOne_Start to execute before executing ServerTwo_Start?
    ServerTwo_Start();
}
```

Comment: Turn the application as "Not responding"? Starting/stopping services doesn't seems to be needed to run on the UI thread. You could use async.  Look for examples on `await Task.Run(() => // start your service);`

Comment: Thank you. I will look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest solution is to make your event handler `async`, and [`await`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/await) a [`Task.Delay`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay).

```
protected async void StartServices_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ServerOne_Start();
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    ServerTwo_Start();
}
```